# Loop through dates to find specific day php SQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, loops, sum

PHP MYSQL - How do I calculate the sum of prices for each day only? How can I tell when a new day starts to begin counting again from 0. Is there a way to say, The day is the 26th now, lets start counting again from 0 in order to save the information separately. In my SQL table I have two columns Price and Lastvisit, the final outcome for the 25th should be 289, and 26th should total 44+90+10 so 144. Please help if you can. Thanks.

- Price
- 20
- 50
- 65
- 55
- 50
- 15
- 34
- 44
- 90
- 10
- Lastvisit
- 2014-09-25
- 2014-09-25
- 2014-09-25
- 2014-09-25
- 2014-09-25
- 2014-09-25
- 2014-09-25
- 2014-09-26
- 2014-09-26
- 2014-09-26

  ```
  <?php
  $date_start = date("Y/m/d"); //Todays Date
  $end_date = date ("Y/m/d", strtotime("last month", strtotime($date_start))); //30 days         prior

  while (strtotime($date_start) >= strtotime($end_date)) { //run through each of the 30 days
  $date_start = date ("Y/m/d", strtotime("-1 day", strtotime($date_start))); //remove 1 day at a time.
  //echo $date_start . "<br>";
  $lastthirtydays .= substr($date_start,8)."|"; //explode each day to plug it in later
  $linegraphq = "SELECT History.Price,History.Lastvisit FROM History WHERE Lastvisit='$date_start'"; //sql 
  $linegraphqresult = mysql_query($linegraphq); ////query
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($linegraphqresult)){ //get all results from query
  $dayofprice .= substr($row['Lastvisit'],8); //explode each DAY # only.
  //echo "COST: " . $row['Price'] . "DATE" . $row['Lastvisit'] . "<br>"; //this is just    the info im working with.
  $finalcost += $row['Price']; //this is summing all of the 30 days pricing
  $pricetoday .= $row['Price'] . "|" . $row['Lastvisit']. "|"; //now you can tell im getting lost...

  }
  }
  echo $dayofprice; //TEST
  echo $pricetoday; //TEST
  $explodedmonth = explode('|',$lastthirtydays);
  $explodedprice = explode('|',$pricetoday);
  //echo $explodedprice[1];
  //echo $finalcost;
  ?>
  ```

Comment: Why are we processing rows from a table RBAR (row by agonizing row)?

Comment: Ugh I know. This code is product of my frustrations. The new complete code is 10 lines total thanks to John. Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something or do you just want the sum?

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS Total
FROM History
GROUP BY Lastvisit;
```

Comment: No, you aren't missing anything. I overcomplicate PHP based on my lack of SQL knowledge. Thanks John, I can stop banging my face against the desk now. Good Day Sir.

Comment: Oh ok :) i was thinking i mustve missed something lol glad i could help! When you can if you could accept the answer it would be greatly appreciated! +1 reciprocated :)